# R: Text in plot with calculated values and greek letters

Tags: r

I am trying to paste a text onto a plot. That text should include a value that has previously been caluclated ("sampleconc") and a greek letter ("mu").
Now I understand how to add greek letters to a text and how to include values, but not how to combine both.

Specifically I want this text to appear:

> Sample = sampleconc "mu"g/mL

Where sampleconc is a value and "mu" the greek letter.
I have tried to add the greek letter using expression(paste(...)) and the value using bquote(Sample == .(sampleconc)), but I don't know how to combine the two without getting an error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has already been asked and answered somewhere, but I haven't found it yet :/

Answer (score 1):

Spacing is tricky with `bquote`.
You can do it like this:

```
a <- 2
plot(1:10, a*(1:10), main = bquote(Sample==.(a)~mu*g/mL))
```